# Uniqueness of distribution and Laplace transform

Tags: probability

Let $X$ and $Y$ be positive random variable.

Show that the following are equivalent:

a) $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution

b)$Ee^{-rX}=Ee^{-rY}$ for every $r$ in $R^+$.

Could anyone kindly help me with this?
I tried to use the definition, but I don't know how to connect these two.

Thanks!

Comment: [This](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/34956/proof-that-moment-generating-functions-uniquely-determine-probability-distributi) might be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to put this in more analytic terms than probabilistic terms; there's one bit I don't quite see how to state probabilistically. Requires a little background in a few areas:

Consider the distributions of $X$ and $Y$. We have two probability measures $\mu$ and $\nu$ on $[0,\infty)$, and $$\int_{[0,\infty)}e^{-rt}\,d\mu(t) =
\int_{[0,\infty)}e^{-rt}\,d\nu(t)\quad(r>0).$$

For complex numbers $z=r+is$ with $r>0$ define $$f(r+is)=
\int_{[0,\infty)}e^{-(r+is)t}\,d\mu(t) -
\int_{[0,\infty)}e^{-(r+is)t}\,d\nu(t).$$The function $f$ is holomorphic (analytic) in the right half-plane; this follows from Fubini's Theorem plus Morera's Theorem, or in various other ways. We have $f(r)=0$ for $r>0$; now a basic uniqueness result for holomorphic functions shows that $f=0$ everywhere in the right half-plane. In particular $$\int_{[0,\infty)}e^{-(1+is)t}\,d\mu(t) =
\int_{[0,\infty)}e^{-(1+is)t}\,d\nu(t)\quad(s\in\mathbb R).$$

Define a (finite) real-valued measure $\lambda$ by $$\int_{[0,1)}\phi(t)\,d\lambda(t)=\int_{[0,\infty)}\phi(t)e^{-t}\,d\mu(t)
-\int_{[0,\infty)}\phi(t)e^{-t}\,d\nu(t).$$The previous display says exactly that $$\hat\lambda=0,$$where $\hat\lambda$ is the Fourier Transform. So uniqueness for the Fourier transform (for complex measures) shows that $\lambda=0$, hence $\mu=\nu$.

Comment: This should also hold for any finite Borel measures on $[0,\infty)$ right?

Comment: Could you add some details on how to show that $f$ is holomorphic using Morera's theorem? First I apply Fubini but what do I do next?

Comment: first you fix a triangle $T$. You need to show $\int_{\partial T}f=0$. Insert the integral defining $f(t)$ and apply Fubini to the resulting double integral. Note that $\int_{[0,\infty)}0=0$.

Comment: If we're talking about an $\Bbb R^d$-valued random variable the distribution is a measure $\mu$ on $\Bbb R^d$. So the Fourier transform is defined on $\Bbb R^d$. I don't know of a suitable analog of "holomorphic" in that setting...