# Identity a Laplace Transform

Tags: probability-distributions, special-functions, laplace-transform

I am looking for a function on the positive real line whose Laplace transform, with parameter $s$, is
$$\left(\frac{\lambda}{1+\lambda}\right)^s,$$
where $s$ and $\lambda$ are greater than $0$.

The answer should be a probability density function on the positive real line, since the Laplace transform is $1$ when $s=0$. Further, when $s \rightarrow \infty$, the Laplace transform tends to $0$. So it is a Laplace transform.

Reference would also be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is $e^{-\tau s}$ in a different notation, with $\tau=-\ln\left(\frac{\lambda}{1+\lambda}\right)$. The [pre-mage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Laplace_transforms#Table) is the shifted delta-function $\delta(t-\tau)$.

Comment: Wow, that is really an answer. Do we have any other options? Say a continuous function or a continuous function with a mass somewhere.

Comment: Laplace transforms are 1-1, so no.

Comment: We need the continuity of integrand to guarantee the Laplace transform is one to one. But delta function is not continuous. Is that right?

Comment: Laplace transform is 1-1 far beyond continuous functions, or even functions, it extends to measures and even distributions.

Comment: I was thinking if two functions are exactly the same on interval $[0,1]$, except at $0.5$. Their Laplace transform, with respect to functions, will still be the same under R-integration. Could you please pass me a reference?

Comment: Sorry, I do not have time to chat. Integrals are insensitive to alteration of a function at a point, so functions equal almost everywhere are taken as the same (it also means they define the same measure). For uniqueness on measures see [Uniqueness of distribution and Laplace transform](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1335333/152568).

Comment: $(\lambda/(1 + \lambda))^s$ does not tend to zero on a vertical line, which is why the inverse transform is not an ordinary function.

Comment: Could you please explain a little bit more?

Comment: Recall that the path for the Bromwich integral is $(\gamma - i \infty, \gamma + i \infty)$; $F(s)$ doesn't live on the real axis. If $F(s) = e^{-\tau s}$ (as pointed out in the first comment) and $s = \gamma + i \sigma$, consider the behavior of $F(s)$ for large real $\sigma$.